# Managing the Test Environment for Power Apps and PowerAutomate with Sharepoint List

Tags: powerapps, power-automate

I have created PowerApps application and Power-Automate flow (to generate excel-reports). I have used the Sharepoint online list as backend. I am wondering how will I manage test and production environment for these Apps.

As PowerApps and PowerAutomate have a direct connection with Sharepoint, is it possible to separate Test and Production Environment wherein the Apps and Flow will be accessing different Sharepoint list?

Answer (score 2):

You can export your power apps using **packaging**, so during the Export, you can manage
how each individual resource will be imported into the target environment during package import.

So During import package import, you have to update the configurations according to the target environment.

For more details, please check the [link](https://powerapps.microsoft.com/pl-pl/blog/powerapps-packaging/).